# Why can't we use the Master Theorem on recurrences with floor or ceiling operations?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, master-theorem, divide-and-conquer

From my understanding, using such operators on large numbers doesn't have an impact on running time, since the integer rounding becomes negligible after a certain point. For example, the recurrence $$T(n)=
\begin{cases}
T(\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor)+(\log(n))^{2}, & \text{if $n>1$} \\
1 & \text{if $n=1.$}
\end{cases}
$$ is unsolvable using the Master Theorem, whereas  $$T(n)=
\begin{cases}
T({n/2})+(\log(n))^{2}, & \text{if $n>1$} \\
1 & \text{if $n=1.$}
\end{cases}
$$ is solvable using the Master Theorem. Why is this?

EDIT: Why doesn't this floored example work? Isn't it monotonically increasing?

Comment: You can use the master theorem on your recurrence with floor.